# Select property after converting a string to jsonb

Tags: postgresql

A column in the postgres DB (14.2) was historically a text before I've started writing serialized json objects into it so current type is text.

Currently most of the rows looking like

```
"{\"RecomendationToFriend\":3,\"Improve\":\"test\"}"
```

What I need is to select `RecomendationToFriend` so I'm converting the column to jsonb using to_jsonb():

```
select to_jsonb(f."Text")->'RecomendationToFriend', to_jsonb(f."Text")  from "Feedback"
```

to_jsonb() seems to work and shows the objects in dbeaver (second column) but trying to retrieve `RecomendationToFriend` out of it return nulls (first column)

[image]

How can I retrieve `RecomendationToFriend` as numbers so I can aggregate them later?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: it's neither code nor error but just the example of data retrieved by my select statement to show what I mean. Everything else is a text

Comment: Nevertheless, readers are not going to expand the image to read it, in order yo help you. You need to make it easy for them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are layers to this mess. At the core, you double-quoted strings that should have been single-quoted, thereby escaping all double-quotes.

To undo, I suggest this simple helper function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_unescape(text, OUT _t text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT E''' || $1 || ''''
   INTO _t;
END
$func$;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Unescape a string with escaped newlines and carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35237937/939860)

You may need to do more. That's also addressed over there.

Then trim leading and trailing double-quote. Assuming there is no leading / trailing white space. Else you need to trim that, too.

An then cast to `::json` or `::jsonb` instead of `to_json()`.

```
SELECT f_unescape(trim("Text", '"'))::json -> 'RecomendationToFriend' AS result
FROM   "Feedback" f;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Tv9bGnwU)

That requires legal JSON as input, though ...

Of course, you should not use "Text" as column name to begin with. That's bad for at least 4 reasons. Nor "Feedback" as table name. Use legal, lower-case, unquoted, descriptive identifiers to avoid more confusion. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just write a migration on the backend then. Regarding naming - they are coming from the default entity frameworkk core configuration. Escaping comes also as the result of .NET serialization